# Updating database using listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I encountered a problem whereby my listbox cannot update data. I have 2 tables, timing and trolleyservice. The listbox reads and show the data from the timing table. both tables were linked. Whenever I update the time in the trolley service table, it prompt me this error:

> The property 'TimingID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Can anyone help about this?

```
private void btnUpdateTS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int ID = Int32.Parse(lblID.Text);
        foreach (timing selectedTiming in lstTime.SelectedItems)
        {
            var EditTS = (from ets in db.trolleyservices
                          where ets.idtrolleyservice == ID
                          select ets).First();
            EditTS.Type = txtType.Text;
            EditTS.TimingID = selectedTiming.TimingID;

            db.SaveChanges();
            txtType.Text = "";
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your trolleyservice has an identity column for TimingID.  So the database will create the key values for you and you cannot set them yourself.

If you want to be able to set that value, perhaps you should consider making it a non-key field.

Comment: The TimingID in my trolleyservice table is to link the Timing table together. Therefore for the listbox, the displaymember is the time and the valuemember is the ID.

Comment: This is difficult without seeing the data model in some way, can you post this up at all?

Answer (score 0):

Need to say object is modified, before save.

```
Database.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(yourObject, EntityState.Modified);
Database.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(<yourObject>, EntityState.Modified);
```

before db.SaveChanges();